# npm not working after clearing cache

Tags: node.js, npm

Before clearing cache

```
npm cache clear
```

npm is working fine. After clearing cache, it is not working. 
The error log below suggest problem with internet connectivity but internet connection is just fine. 
This problem does not only happen for bower but for any modules.

Here's the output of process:

```
> sudo npm install -g bower Password: npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/bower npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/bower npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/bower npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
> npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
> ERR! network and is related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network
> In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm
> ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make
> sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See:
> 'npm help config'
> 
> npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0 npm ERR! command
> "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.16/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
> "install" "-g" "bower" npm ERR! cwd /Users/username npm ERR!
> node -v v0.10.16 npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8 npm ERR! syscall connect npm
> ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!    
> /Users/username/npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: did you figure out what was causing the issue - are you using a proxy to connect externally?

Comment: The question here asked about "npm cache clear" but the body of the question shows output from "npm install" instead, which clearly reports an ETIMEOUT. Error, since the OP hasn't clarified in about 2 years, I think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 221):

This worked for me:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows 10 (no errors, just did nothing). I had to manually delete all the folders within `%appdata%\npm-cache`

Comment: Thanks, Did work for my computer with --force addition (WIN 10)

Comment: `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.` Be careful with the force usage, little jedi

Answer (score 149):

It should be

```
npm cache clean
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Comment: This answer may have been correct at the time, when npm was at version 1.3.8 as mentioned in the question. However, in `npm` [2.8.3](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/9a1221a7a175f57502407954471db2d3b7cf93c6/lib/cache.js#L119) and `npm` [3.3.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/9a1221a7a175f57502407954471db2d3b7cf93c6/lib/cache.js#L119), "clear" is a silent alias for "clean", so it would do the same thing.

Comment: resource not found in your shared link

Answer (score 74):

"As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use

```
npm cache verify
```

instead."

Comment: "cache" and "guaranteed to be valid" do not belong in the same sentence.

Comment: @gburton, this is the npm documentation copied straight from the terminal.

Comment: then i guess the message from NPM is wrong. Nothing is guaranteed to self heal. We don't live in a land of magic.

Comment: @RBZ please include the command that you used to generate that help statement.

Comment: @JosephHarriott You can run npm cache clean to see the exact message

Comment: https://twitter.com/npmstatus/status/1291318846205210624 
Cache is often the source of a problem. It's normal. I fully agree with @gburton and I don't believe in self-healing magic.

Answer (score 33):

try this one 
`npm cache clean --force` 
after that run 
`npm cache verify`

Answer (score 18):

Try `npm cache clean --force` if it doesn't work then manually delete %appdata%\npm-cache folder.

and install `npm install npm@latest -g`

It worked for me.

[visit this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html)

Answer (score 13):

I try to

```
npm cache clean
```

But npm said newer version on npm (> 5) has self healing Mechanism
and every thing i need to do for checking npm is use verify

```
npm cache verify
```

npm message :

```
The npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. 

If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
```

but for forcing npm use this:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 7):

Try `npm cache clean --force` if it doesn't work then manually delete `%appdata%\npm-cache` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Environment path may have been removed.

Check it by typing,

`npm config get prefix`

This must be the location where the npm binaries are found.

In windows, `c:/users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm` is the place where they are found.

Add this location to the environment variable. It should work fine.

(Control Panel -> Search for 'Environment Variables' and click on a button with that name -> edit Path -> add the above location)

Comment: This is highly unlikely the be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

at npm@6.8.0 the command that is been supported is `npm cache verify`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running cmd as an administrator.
before that, I was trying to run in vs code.

run it in Power Shell or Cmd with administrative privilege. I hope that it will help.

```
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
npm cache clean
```

after that run

```
npm cache verify
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.