# Npm install : FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/... failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

Tags: npm, raspberry-pi, npm-install

Trying to install any node package using npm hangs for about 5 mins then gives a ECONNRESET network error. I have been using npm for other projects recently and it worked fine but now will not work for any project(Including clean npm init)

```
npm i ws
```

This is on a Raspberry pi 3 running on my home network with no proxy requirements. All other machines both linux and windows are working fine.

```
npm -v = 6.4.1
```

I have tried the following:

1. `npm i ws` This gives me the ECONNRESET error (See below)
2. `Curl https://registry.npmjs.org/`
   & `Curl https://registry.npmjs.org/ws`
   Both return the correct json response
3. Removing any proxy settings

```
    npm config rm proxy
    npm config rm https-proxy
    npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

4. Restarting etc

Full Error log:

```
npm i ws --save --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'i',
npm verb cli   'ws',
npm verb cli   '--save',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v8.16.0
npm verb npm-session 0a9bedb5def7f4a1
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 6ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1146975ms
npm verb type system
npm verb stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/ws failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm verb stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm verb stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
npm verb stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm verb stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
npm verb stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
npm verb stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
npm verb cwd /home/pi/projects/picamera/node_server
npm verb Linux 4.19.37-v7+
npm verb argv "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/node" "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/npm" "i" "ws" "--save" "--verbose"
npm verb node v8.16.0
npm verb npm  v6.4.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/ws failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 1148813ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2019-05-10T23_28_17_769Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Also recent system changes...
Installed motion https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842894/7470045

Comment: Thanks. It turned out there was an issue with the ethernet connection conflicting with npm. I unplugged the ethernet cable and everything worked again. Not sure why this would cause proxy issues though.

Answer (score 5):

First check following thing:

```
ping registry.npmjs.org
```

You will get to know the IP address from that like below:

**PING registry.npmjs.org (104.16.20.35) 56(84) bytes of data.**
Then

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
104.16.20.35 registry.npmjs.org
```

Then try to do following

```
npm install
```