# npm build is getting failed inside docker based build agents of ADO inside AKS

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-pipelines, node-modules, npm-install

We are trying to run our Azurdevops buildagent inside AKS and I used below docker command part to install the node and npm capabilities for the ubuntu based buildagent.

```
#install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN apt-get install g++ build-essential
```

Also `install nodejs` task in the Azuredevops pipeline getting succeded with below output.

```
Found tool in cache: node 16.14.2 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /azp/_work/_tool/node/16.14.2/x64/bin
```

But when we run nmp build tasks, its failing with below error. Not sure why its trying to install npm again as we alreay have the npm nstalled it with dockerfile and also wit the azuretask its installed.

Is  there any way to pass the npm installation steps again as we dont have internet connectivity to the github urls from these pods.

```
v16.14.2
8.5.0
npm cache location
/mnt/npmrepo
cleaning up workspace
Installing angular/cli

changed 214 packages in 7s
Running npm install
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated messageformat@2.3.0: Package renamed as '@messageformat/core', see messageformat.github.io for more details. 'messageformat@4' will eventually provide a polyfill for Intl.MessageFormat, once it's been defined by Unicode & ECMA.
npm WARN deprecated protractor@7.0.0: We have news to share - Protractor is deprecated and will reach end-of-life by Summer 2023. To learn more and find out about other options please refer to this post on the Angular blog. Thank you for using and contributing to Protractor. https://goo.gle/state-of-e2e-in-angular
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.20.3: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.6.9 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.2/node-v16.14.2-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.2/node-v16.14.2-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:110:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:538:35)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1086-azure
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/azp/_work/_tool/node/16.14.2/x64/bin/node" "/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 

npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.2/node-v16.14.2-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:110:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:538:35)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1086-azure
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/azp/_work/_tool/node/16.14.2/x64/bin/node" "/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
npm ERR! Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/npmrepo/_logs/2022-11-16T14_47_37_182Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Check about this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089238/npm-install-fetcherror-request-to-http-registry-npmjs-org-failed-reaso).

Comment: But here its asking to enable the connectivity to the nodejs registry. We dont have internet inside and hence we installed the npm as package of dockerfile itself. Our concern is why its again trying for npm install eventhough its already installed.

Comment: is there any way to get succeeded with offline or can we add any part of this to Docker file  so that I can build the image from somewhere where internet is already enabled.