# Moving nodejs project from a pc to another

Tags: node.js

Im really need to nodejs, I have created a project thats running fine on my linux laptop and I have zipped the files up and moved them into my desktop.

On my windows box I went into the directory and did an "npm install" and that went well. However when I run the "npm run dev" command I get the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~predev: coreapi@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: coreapi@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\user1\Desktop\NodeFiles\coreapi\node_modules\.bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hyland\Alt ActiveX\;C:\Program Files (x86)\wfavvid_1061;C:\Program Files (x86)\wfavvid_1061\lib\;C:\Program Files (x86)\wfavvid_1061\java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: CWD: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\NodeFiles\coreapi
10 silly lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec "babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0"'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle coreapi@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: coreapi@1.0.0 dev: `NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec "babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid coreapi@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\user1\Desktop\NodeFiles\coreapi\src
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error coreapi@1.0.0 dev: `NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec "babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the coreapi@1.0.0 dev script.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try deleting node_modules and doing npm install again?

Comment: I just tried that and Im getting the same error :-/

Comment: From what I understand from the Error Log. These answers may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259492/npm-not-working-after-clearing-cache