# Why does this webpack export mess up?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Webpack export turns into webpack_exports_.d.e.f.a.u.l.t

How is this possible?
I have tried messing around with npm and node versions to make sure its not that.
I think it has got something to do with babel or similiar.

Edit: doesn't happen when manually deselecting babel and only using eslint

Please let me know if you require any additional Project/Config files.
It is a fresh with vue-cli created Vue3 Project.

```
> vue create appname
( ...vue3, default config no manual selection )
> npm run serve
```

[image: Dev Console Error]

Comment: What is vue-create? Did you mean vue create? If Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It obviously can't be reproduced that easily with Vue CLI, otherwise the tool would be unusable. In your case this likely means that it needs to be a repo, make sure it reproduces the error when you clone and init it from scratch. No need to mess with Node an npm, use the latest even Node version and the latest npm version.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes sorry for the confusion. I meant vue create and yes it has not really got something to do with it. It must be something locally messing it up. Im not sure how to reproduce it else where. It works on another machine. I was hoping someone had this issue before.

Comment: No, it's not something usual. Can't happen under normal circumstances. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors for the future questions. This prevents the error from being copied as is and searched. It's unknown how you've got `vue` command. In case you installed it globally, uninstall it and use `npx @vue/cli` instead. Clear npm cache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259492 . Use the versions that were suggested above, i.e. Node 18.

Comment: Possibly this problem. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17213 . In case it was the case, it can be seen it's already fixed and shouldn't affect fresh installations

Comment: @EstusFlask you're right, it most likely had something to do with the issue you mentioned.
 github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17213
I have just retried creating a new app and it works now. Awesome.

Comment: And yes thanks for the heads up about the image I forgot about that in frustration yesterday evening haha! And ty for pointing me to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was most likely related to [github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17213](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17213)

I created a new app now after seeing they implemented a patch and it works again.